# Widget page stopped loading

Tags: widgets, wp-admin

I'm currently having an issue with the widgets page in the backend. however I'm having a heck of a time identifying what's break the page.

I've found there are 3 widgets that when removed from the theme, the page loads correctly. The page stops loading before the widget description in the left column of the page. Has anyone experienced this?

I believe it may have something to do with the admin forms of the widgets, but I can't seem to find an issue or an error (even after turning on debug)..

Answer (score 1):

Issues like this can be difficult to track down at times. You've started down the correct path by narrowing the scope of the issue down to those 3 widgets.

If there is any additional information such as the name of the theme and the widgets you've found to cause the issue that would be helpful. Of course, if we're talking about a custom theme or widgets then providing source code examples will be your best bet.

A couple of things to try:

1) While debugging is turned on check your XHR / AJAX console for requests occurring in the background that might be failing.

2) Check your Javascript console for any frontend errors that might be preventing the page from finishing.

3) Check the source code of the 3 offending widgets to see what they might have in common such as similar fields, script references or hooks.

FWIW, I would have preferred to add this information as a comment but my REP isn't high enough yet. I hope this helps.